How to calculate rate shocked bond future prices (effective duration)
I am looking to build out parallel interest rate shocks for a treasury future.  I know how to calculate the cheapest to deliver in the base case and how to calculate the theoretical future price using cost of carry formula:
F0 = (S0 - I) * e^(rT)
Where:

F0 = Theoretical Futures Price
S0 = Spot Price
I = Present Value of Coupons
r = Financing Rate
T = Time to Future's Delivery Date in years

However, I'm not sure what the convention is on interest rate shocks.
In a shock scenario the cheapest to deliver could theoretically change, but you'd need to know the cheapest to deliver in order to calculate the theoretical future price for a given rate shock.  You need the future price to calculate the cheapest to deliver.
Questions:

Given the circular reference, is it best practice to assume that the cheapest to deliver security remains the same, and simply shock that security's price, then input that to the theoretical future price formula?  Or is there some sort of iterative solution?
Is using the theoretical future price to calculate the price for the shocks the correct approach?
For the delivery options' value, is it usually taken into account or handwaved away?  The value could be determined in the base case, is it good enough to apply that value to all the shocked prices, or is a more quantitative approach usually used?


You don't need the bond future price to compute the CTD.
Many people use the IRR to select the CTD, but this is the circular argument: in reality a futures contract is an option on a basket of bonds, and it should be priceable from the bonds. Since the futures is a lot more liquid than bonds, people look at it the wrong way round and we have circular dependency.
Your formula above misses the Conversion Factor and should read as
$F0=\min_i \frac{(S0_i - I_i) * e^{r_i T}}{CF_i}$
(assuming by Spot Price you mean Dirty Price)
This does not take into account the option, which can be incorporated with more or less complex stochastic rate models.
Then, if you rather not make it too complicated, you can fix the CTD, which is valid for small shocks.

Thanks, you are correct that I am using dirty price as spot and I left out that the formula does need normalized by the conversion factor to get the theoretical future price, it also needs accrued interest subtracted out before normalizing.  Using the minimum theoretical future price as the cheapest to deliver for the shocks agrees with what I am seeing in "Understanding Treasury Bond Futures" by Salomon Brothers.

Or "The Treasury Bond Basis" is another very good reference.
